# Add attachment to Soap message outside SoapEnveloppe

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I'm sending data to a Soap webservice successful. However now I need to add attachtments (jpg or xlsx) files to the Soap message, outside the SoapEnveloppe. How would I go about that in C#. I see it can be done, but I can't find an C# example.

```
using (var svc = new TestService.TestServiceCreate_outService())
{
    svc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["User"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pwd"]);

    // fill request properties
    ..... ok

    // add attachments?
    .. how?

    // sent request
    svc.Create(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use for this purpose DIME Service, look [here as msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms824597.aspx).

another link you can use [this link](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363957/Sending-Attachments-with-SOAP).